# nginx: default_server directive not respected

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have multiple files each with a config for a different vhost.
On one of these config files (included in the main nginx config file) I set the default_server directive:

```
server {

    listen                  80;
    listen                  443 ssl default_server spdy;
    server_name             188.166.X.XXX;
    root                    /var/www/default;
    index                   index.php index.html;
    ...
}
```

... but it's not respected. If I point the A record of a domain I didn't add in a nginx server block, the first server block in alphabetical order is picked up (instead of the default_server).
Why?

Comment: You have `default_sever` only on port 443. Do you use https?

Comment: on that site (the one with default_server set) yes. but not on all of my sites.

Comment: Well then, what are all other `listen` directive?

Comment: In vhosts that use https I have `listen 80; listen 443 ssl spdy;`, if they use only http I have just `listen 80;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `default_server` needs to be set for every port you use in your configuration. So, you need to add `default_server` after `listen 80;` to the virtual host you want to be the default server for port 80.

Comment: Yep! Worked.. :)